# ExtJs : PageSize

Tags: sql, extjs, store, paging

Hello im trying to set my page size but it doesnt work right :/ i get at the second page the same result as in the first one. The pagingbar shows 1-25 results but 27 are displayed at the second page 26-27 but it is the same result as in the first page. Im getting the data from Sql select ... select * from example_table i know i can limit 25 but this is not the right solution cause i cant get the whole data from select if i do this, this way! Why i cant display it right? Thank u!

```
Ext.define('Shopware.apps.UnSqlReader.controller.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
init: function () {
var me = this;
me.mainWindow = me.getView('window.Window').create({}).show();

me.control({
    'main-window-view': {
    onSqlChange: me.onSqlChange
    }
})
},
onSqlChange: function (gridPanel, value) {
var me = this;
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '{url action=getColumns}',
    params: {
    fileName: value
    },
    success: function (response) {
    var responseObj = JSON.parse(response.responseText),
        grid = me.mainWindow.grid,
        pagingbar = me.mainWindow.pagingBar,
        columns = new Array(),
        gridColums = new Array();
    responseObj.columns.forEach(function (item) {
        columns.push({
        name: item,
        type: 'string',
        });
        gridColums.push({
        text: Ext.String.capitalize(item),
        dataIndex: item,
        renderer: function (val, meta) {
            meta.tdAttr = 'data-qtip="' + val.replace(/['"]+/g, '&quot;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;') + '"';
            return val;
        }
        });
    });
    var SqlResult = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields: columns,
        remoteFilter: true,
        pageSize: 25,
        proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '{url action=getSqlDetails}',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data'
        }
        },
    });
    SqlResult.getProxy().extraParams.fileName = value;
    SqlResult.load();
    grid.reconfigure(SqlResult, gridColums);
    pagingbar.bindStore(SqlResult);
    grid.show();
    }
});
}
```

});

[image]

here the fulll php function

```
   public function getSqlDetailsAction() {
$fileName = $this->Request()->getParam('fileName');
$pluginFolder = dirname(dirname(__DIR__));
$sqlFolder = $pluginFolder . '/SqlFiles/';
$filePath = $sqlFolder . $fileName;
$sql = file_get_contents($filePath);
$sqlResultList = Shopware()->Db()->query($sql);
$columns = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $sqlResultList->columnCount(); $i++) {
    $columns[$i] = $sqlResultList->getColumnMeta($i)["name"];
}
$this->View()->success = true;
$this->View()->columns = $columns;
$this->View()->data = $sqlResultList->fetchAll();
}
```

}`

would be nice if anyone can help to implement an ofset for  : `data = $sqlResultList->`

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, that is the way to do it. The pageSize parameter will only set a query parameter when you send the request so the server can return the correct amount: [Combobox paging toolbar dosn't respond to page size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29398495/combobox-paging-toolbar-dosnt-respond-to-page-size/29398722#29398722)

There is an option to load the entire request at once and have in memory paging (https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.ux.data.PagingMemoryProxy). However, you can only sort whats on the screen and I think only filter what's on the screen. Example of that here: http://extjs.eu/example-grid-memory-paging/

Comment: :( this make me so sad :( but why the pagingbar can display it right? and the grid not?

Comment: The paging bar is just starting at 0 and adding/subtracting the pageSize on each button press. I don't know the internals, but I think Sencha's main reason for not implementing this by now it is "if you don't implement server paging, you probably don't need client paging."

In this case though, removing the paging toolbar will probably give you enough room to fit the last two records!

Comment: how about php offset cause i get the data from there but my php skills are to low to handle this ! here my php code snippet `$sqlResultList = Shopware()->Db()->query($sql);` which i put in the store in extjs. i excute $sql with this methoode : how can i set sqlresult offset to 25 .. ? do u have maybe an idea.

Comment: I am not to familiar with php, but you just need to append "LIMIT x OFFSET y" to your sql query ("LIMIT 25" to limit to 25). I believe ExtJS sends a "limit" query parameter for pageSize and a "start" query parameter for the record index to start with.